# Does Earlgrey for iOS support UI elements outside of the test app?

Tags: ios-ui-automation, earlgrey

I am totally new to iOS, Xcode and automated test frameworks.

I would like to confirm 3 things about iOS testing using EarlGrey:

1. It cannot access elements outside of the test app. For example, the test app cannot press the 'HOME' key
2. It does not support the 'swipe up' gesture to bring up the control centre
3. It cannot not put a test app in background and then bring it to the foreground

If I understand correctly, EarlGrey only allows control of the UI elements defined inside the test app.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you are right but Out-of-app interaction is being worked on please follow along [here](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues/63).